# Cannot cannot to database using sql developer: a connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period

Tags: windows, oracle-sql-developer

I am using a windows laptop and installed sql developer version 23.1.0. When I input the connection details for my database I get the following error:

> a connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

My colleagues, using a macbook, are able to connect using the same creds. Anyone have any idea what is going on?

I have searched the web but nothing is helping so far.

Connection to the oracle database should be successful.

Comment: can you connect via SQL plus?

Comment: Do you have the same Java and JDBC driver versions as yoru colleagues?

Comment: @SergeyA: No I cannot with Sql plus either. I get the following error: "ERROR:
ORA-12637: Packet receive failed"

Comment: @mustaccio: We have the same java version installed. Dont think jdbc matters since we are not connecting via code?

Comment: What do you think SQL Developer uses to connect to the databases?

Comment: Sorry I mean, I did not explicitly download jdbc drivers. I am guessing it should be a part of oracle sql developer installation, right?

Comment: Do you have SQL ALG (Juniper firewall)?

Comment: Sorry noob question. How can I find out if I do? I do not have juniper installed on my computer if that helps

Comment: @mustaccio: Any help would be highly appreciated. I am really desperate at this point.

Comment: I understand your frustration, but unfortunatly the fact that you are desperate is not relevant to solving the problem. Clearly, there are some material differences between your computer and those of your colleagues, and the only way forward is to find what those differences are, which is done by eliminating the layers of complexity, one by one. Since both SQL Developer and SQL*Plus fail to connect, it's likely that the problem lies outside these programs, perhaps in the firewall and/or network driver configuration, or the SSL certificates (if you use SSL).

Comment: Enter "ORA-12637: Packet receive failed" in your favourite search engine, and it might provide some useful hints.